# Calling a python function within Express route

Tags: python, node.js, express

I am trying run a python function in my express route using child processes.

When the client sends over  `GET` request for a particular route, I have some computations to be made using python; so I want to run the program and get the result for that route only.

I have looked around the internet a bit and have tried child-processes, however, they do not seem to work.

**What I have tried so far:**

After looking at a similar question here at SO, I tried this:

```
router.get('/computation',  function(req, res, next) {

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,

    compute = spawn('python', ['compute.py']);

compute.stdout.on('data', function(data){

    console.log(data.toString());

  });

  compute.stdin.write(JSON.stringify("Hello"));
  compute.stdin.end();
});
```

The python code is like this:

```
main()
 res = compute()
 print( res )
```

When I try this, nothing happens, no error code in the console; not even a 500 code. The browser keeps on reloading.

Comment: Please expand on *"do not seem to work"* with a [mcve].

Comment: Have you considered proxying the request? For maximum performance, you'd want to have the Python script run persistently as a worker which can be interacted with via messages. HTTP would be a natural fit. Python runs in a small HTTP server, and node just proxies the request through...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I will update the code.

Comment: @deceze So, should I create a new endpoint on my express server and send requests to that from python code?

Comment: I don't know if or why you'd have to create a new endpoint. All I'm saying is that a persistently running Python worker and HTTP communication between node and that Python worker is a very reasonable option.

Comment: @deceze How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look for a simple HTTP server in Python like Flask or Tornado, then make an HTTP request to that from node.